# Signed Android app won't install on Galaxy S20

Tags: java, android, apk, failed-installation, android-app-signing

I made an Android app (Java/Kotlin) and I've been testing it on different devices. When testing on a Galaxy S20 I get this error upon downloading the apk:

"Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_RESOURCES_ARSC_COMPRESSED

List of apks:
'C:/Users/....'
Installation failed due to [...] -124"

- I'm able to download and install the unsigned version of the app, just not the signed version.
- I only have one Galaxy S20 to test, so not sure if it's the specific device.
- Have not been able to replicate this problem on any other devices
- The app is not coming from the Play Store, it's being directly
  installed via Profile/Debug in Android Studio

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I think I narrowed it down to the signing of the app, but I'm not sure why the issue would be isolated for the Galaxy S20. Could it be that the S20 does not accept the hashing algorithm I used for the signing isn't secure enough for such a new device?

Answer (score 0):

First enbale verify apps over usb and set logging level to off.

I hope this works

Comment: Unfortunately it did not - the unsigned version is able to be installed via USB and runs fine, just not the signed version. One thing I failed to mention before was that the app fails to **download** via BOTH USB and MS Company Portal (it's deployed to prod). I'm inclined to think there's a problem with my code because of my experience level, but the app works fine on every phone EXCEPT a Galaxy S20 (and I don't have the resources to test on a different S20)..... I'm at a dead end, should I try to troubleshoot with Samsung, Google, Microsoft on this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using jarsigner to sign the app. jarsigner no longer works for SDK 30+, so this is why it wouldn't download onto the Galaxy S20. Everything worked fine once I switched to apksigner